# Regarding alternate approach (using class methods and variables) to global variables in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, model, singleton

I remember having struggled at a particular time of my learning phase with implementing the concept of 'global' variables in iOS that can be accessed on any class throughout the app. I read through many excellent tutorials like this one by [Matt Galloway](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/).

I just went through the code I had finally implemented and I realize I had done it in a very different way than any of these tutorials. I wanted to know the possible disadvantages/advantages of the method I adopted

My h file was something like :

```
@interface GlobalVariables : NSObject

+(void)setUsername:(NSString *)string;
+(NSString *)getUsername;

@end
```

and my m file was :

```
static NSString *name;

@implementation GlobalVariables

+(void)setUsername:(NSString *)string{
    name = string;
}
+(NSString *)getUsername{
    return name;
}

@end
```

I'd set the global variable in any other class like

```
[GlobalVariables setUsername:@"user1"];
```

and get it in other classes as

```
self.nameLabel.text = [GlobalVariables getUsername];
```

Is there anything wrong/right about what I did? Any comment towards the right direction would be much appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: If you're going to implement something as you describe here, you would be (IMO) better off making your data be instance variables of a singleton (which would typically include having a single static to point to that singleton). That opinion being stated, there's nothing wrong with your approach.

Comment: What if you made these properties of your app delegate? That would work perfectly with a singleton instance as @mah suggested.

Comment: @mah, I guess the reasoning for my approach was that having them as instance variable would result in having to instantiate the class every time I needed access to the variable. If my approach doesn't have anything wrong per se, then I guess the compactness was probably an advantage that I saw at that time :) Thank you for your input!

Comment: @EricAmorde, I did consider having them as properties in the app delegate, but I remember having read somewhere that the true purpose of app delegate is to handle app events and not to handle global variables. It could also become messy with too many global variables. 
With this approach, I can at least put variables of similar kind into separate classes.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is smelly but how you are doing it is fine (almost - see below)...

basically there are unavoidable situations where you need to store global state...

you should try as hard as you can to avoid them... here are my ramblings:

If the state you are keeping is truly global and infrequently accessed, then store them in the user defaults using `NSUserDefaults`:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"123456789" forKey:@"apiKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

if your state isn't truly 'global' then you should try to find the correct context, even if it is an artificial one:

```
@interface EncryptionContext: NSObject
    @property int someProperty
@end
```

What you are doing is fine, and I prefer it to a singleton... basically anything you can do with a singleton you can do with a `+[Class classMethod]` or even a `nakedCFunction()`

in a multithreaded app be sure to `@synchronize` your accessors and setters so that they are always in a consistent state.

In reference counted code you will want to retain the new objects and release the old ones...

```
static NSString *name;

@implementation GlobalVariables

+(void)setUsername:(NSString *)string{

    id tmp = name;
    name = [string copy];
    [tmp release];
}
+(NSString *)getUsername{
    return name;
    //or for more atomic operation [[name copy] autorelease]
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for that detailed answer :) By context, do you mean managed contexts as in core data? I don't know much in detail about them but i _have_ read about it.

Comment: No not necessarily, just an object that will accompany the whole operation... ie, if the operation is a URL Connection you may have a URLConnectionContext that collects all of the data and reports the success or failure of the operation. or if your operation is some complicated calculation, you may have an object that holds aspects of the calculation as variables... basically just an entity that can hold state in an atomic way so that you can throw it away and start over at the appropriate times, and it isn't polluted by doing the operation in parallel.